# Regex help (extracting data between hr tags)

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to extract teaser text within TinyMCE in a PHP CMS. The `<hr />` tag is not used within my design, so I'd like to extract the text in the following scenarios, based on the assumption that the content administrator will ONLY use them to define Teaser text:

1. Extract content before an `<hr />` tag (in the situation the content administrator enters the teaser text at the beginning of the RTE, and then uses `<hr />` as the cuttof point)
2. Extract the content between 2 `<hr />` tags (in the situation where the content administrator enters the teaser text anywhere within the content, and indicates it with `<hr />` tags on either side.

What regex should I use to cover the above?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get your question correctly but here's a try:

```
if (preg_match('~^(.*?)<hr />((.+?)<hr />)?~is', $test, $matches)) {
  // at least one <hr /> present

  if (empty($matches[2])) {
    // no second <hr />
    $teaser = $matches[1];

  } else {
    // there is a second <hr />
    $teaser = $matches[3];
  }
} else {
  // no teaser
  $teaser = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 
$strs = array(
   'GET ME A <hr /> bla',
   'Bla bla<hr /> GET ME B <hr />'
);
 
foreach($strs as $str) {
 
    $a = preg_match_all('/(<hr \/>)?(?P<teaser>.*?)<hr \/>/', $str, $matches);
 
    var_dump($a, $matches);
 
}
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/QlmEl).

#### Output

```
int(1)
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "GET ME A <hr />"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["teaser"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "GET ME A "
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "GET ME A "
  }
}
int(2)
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "Bla bla<hr />"
    [1]=>
    string(16) " GET ME B <hr />"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["teaser"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Bla bla"
    [1]=>
    string(10) " GET ME B "
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Bla bla"
    [1]=>
    string(10) " GET ME B "
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This tested function does the trick:

```php
function get_teaser($text) {
    // First count how many <hr/> tags there are.
    $count = preg_match_all('%<hr\s*/?>%i', $text, $matches);
    if (!$count) return ''; // None? return empty string.
    switch($count) {
    case (1): // Case I: From start up to only HR tag.
        preg_match('%^(.*?)<hr\s*/?>%si', $text, $matches);
        return $matches[1];
        break;
    case (2): // Case II: Stuff between two HR tags.
        preg_match('%<hr\s*/?>(.*?)<hr\s*/?>%si', $text, $matches);
        return $matches[1];
        break;
    default: // Case III: Three or more HR tags is an error.
        return 'Error! Too many <hr /> tags.';
    }
}
```

This also allows for various HR tag forms: e.g. `<hr>`, `<hr/>`, `<hr   />`.